# Using ocgx, pgfplots packages to create a clickable pdf file, use in Microsoft Powerpoint?

Tags: pgfplots, powerpoint, ocgx

So using a simple example of a .tex file to get a clickable pdf, I want to then take the pdf image and use it in a powerpoint presentation. So I could be presenting in powerpoint, and click on the objects in the pdf to change visibility of the graph like in the example code below. I can load the pdf into powerpoint like normal, but it loses the clickable functionality. Any ideas?!?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ocgx,calc}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{ocg button/.style={circle,minimum size=.5em,switch ocg with mark on={#1}{}}}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,ocg={name=Layer 1,ref=layer1}]
    \begin{scope}[shift={(current page)}]
      \fill[red,fill opacity=.5] (120:1cm) circle [radius=1.5cm];
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,ocg={name=Layer 2,ref=layer2}]
    \begin{scope}[shift={(current page)}]
      \fill[blue,fill opacity=.5] (240:1cm) circle [radius=1.5cm];
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,ocg={name=Layer 3,ref=layer3}]
    \begin{scope}[shift={(current page)}]
      \fill[green,fill opacity=.5] (0:1cm) circle [radius=1.5cm];
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item Layer 1 \tikz\node[fill=red!50,ocg button=layer1]{};
  \item Layer 2 \tikz\node[fill=blue!50,ocg button=layer2]{};
  \item Layer 3 \tikz\node[fill=green!50,ocg button=layer3]{};
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: At a rough guess PowerPoint is not a pdf presenter, and as such cant run any imbedded code the way Acrobat can with its JavaScript support. Perhaps you need to use Acrobat reader to run the embedded programs or convert PDF to PowerPoint and add its own scripted controls. I guess this may be classed "off topic" by Latex Mods however I think it helps others to see an answer as to why a Latex feature may not be available to some users. Perhaps you could test in powerpoint settings if pdfs from other presentation sources can run without similar issues and modify question or provide your own answer

Comment: I suggest you amend Question to something like "How can I adapt my LaTeX Animation to suit PowerPoint ?"

Comment: Btw., `ocgx` is a bit dated, use `ocgx2` instead: `\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}`, and remove `\usetikzlibrary{ocgx}`.

Comment: PDF Layers are a PDF feature. What you see in PPT is a screenshot / converted to bitmap version of the PDF and thus no more PDF. That's why the layers are gone in PPT.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear from the second option on [this page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-pdf-file-content-into-a-powerpoint-presentation-5e7719d5-508c-4c07-a3d4-68123c373a62) that you can import a LaTeX generated pdf to a slide then select it to be opened so that you can activate any LaTeX imbedded controls (Presuming you also have Acrobat or similar JavaScript enabled viewer installed).

from the description "This makes the PDF file part of the presentation file. The quality of the PDF file is reduced with this method, but you can open the full PDF file by double-clicking the image when viewing or editing in Normal view"

The alternative as per first option would be to use LaTeX to export PNG or single PDF pages to be added page by page to the PPT with similar PowerPoint controls.